# How can I create 'gch.app' such that "open -a gch page.html" works like "open -a Google\ Chrome page.html"?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, command-line, symlink

I type `open -a` all the time from the terminal, and more often than not the application I want is `Google Chrome.app`, so I end up entering things along the lines of:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome some_file.html
```

I'd like to create a symlink/shortcut to `/Applications/Google Chrome.app` named `gch.app` or what have you, so I can `open -a gch foo.html` which is slightly quicker.

Admittedly it'd take months+ to recoup the amount of time it's taken me to ask this question...  I know I could create zsh aliases and/or bash functions for this kind of thing but I'm relatively new to OSX and want to learn.

My first intuition was to try things along the lines of:

```
ln -s /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app /Applications/gch.app
```

but no dice were had.

Comment: Do you want to put it in the dock? I'm searching for something like this, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application name is defined by the application itself, there is no easy way to use a different one for `open`. So in this case using an alias is probably the best option

```
alias gch='open -a Google\ Chrome'
```

Alternatively you could define Chrome as the default application for html files and just use `open some_file.html`.